# Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, momentjs

while implementing search by date from postgres db using sequelize postgres and nodejs I got this warning.

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged.

```
router.get("/:key", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const searchActivity = await initActivityModel();
    let data = await searchActivity.findAll({
      where: {
       ...
        createdAt: { [Op.like]: "%" + req.params.key + "%" }, 
       // createdAt: { [Op.between]: ["2023-01-06", "2023-01-07"] }, // this is working

      },
    });
```

I'm trying to create a moment object with a date string that is not in a recognized format. how to fix this?

Comment: "*I'm trying to create a moment object*" - where in the code you posted does that happen?

Comment: This `createdAt: { [Op.like]: "%" + req.params.key + "%" }` looks like a string operation(`LIKE`) that you are trying to do on this `createdAt` which I am assuming is a datetime value. The error I pretty sure is coming from `"%" + req.params.key + "%"` where the `%<some_date_string>%` is definitely not a  *... RFC2822 or ISO format.*  string.

Comment: I have passed the `startDate` and `endDate`  query parameters and used these parameters to filter the results from DB. ` where: {createdAt: { [Op.between]: [startDate, endDate] },},`. it works for me.